# Python slicing tuples from list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to extract the values `76212` & `160008` from my result which is below:

```
[(76212, 160008)]
```

For example I want:

```
Result1 = 76212
Result2 = 160008
```

How do I achieve this?

**EDIT**
Should probably add that this result is taken from SQLAlchemy ORM. My code for this is below:

```
query1 = session.query(X.Y,Z.A) \
        .filter(cast(X.Y, VARCHAR).like(f'%{jobno}')) \
        .all()
    print(query1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that complicated, but I guess you need to take some basic python course first. Before asking here on SO.

```
a = [(76212, 160008)]
Result1 = a[0][0]
Result2 = a[0][1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have taken a python course on Udemy but this wasn't covered. I also was unsure if extracting the result via SQLAlchemy affected the way this was to be sliced. Thanks, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your result is named result:

```
result1, result2 = result[0]
```

For some more understanding, consider a tuple:

```
x, y, z = (1, 2, 3)

>>x
1
>>z
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [(76212, 160008)]
result1, result2 = result[0]
```